# IIS not gzipping large dynamic JSON response

Tags: iis, gzip, iis-8

I see other responses from same server getting gzipped. I have a certain URL that is not getting gzipped. I can only think the problem may be the size of the content but I see no setting in IIS 8 that pertains to a size limit.

All static and dynamic and url and http compression is installed and enabled. I can't find any logs that contain any helpful info on why this URL is not getting compressed.

For example, a response that is gzipped from IIS. (See response header `Content-Encoding: gzip`)

```
curl 'http://....../small_json/' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' --compressed -D /tmp/headers.txt -o /dev/null; cat /tmp/headers.txt
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 65382  100 65382    0     0   233k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  233k
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Language: en
Vary: Accept, Accept-Language, Cookie,Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Date: Sun, 08 Apr 2018 01:50:54 GMT
Content-Length: 65382
```

Larger JSON response does not have `Content-Encoding: gzip`:

```
curl 'http://....../big_json/'  -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' --compressed -D /tmp/headers.txt -o /dev/null; cat /tmp/headers.txt
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 4755k    0 4755k    0     0  1018k      0 --:--:--  0:00:04 --:--:-- 1373k

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Language: en
Vary: Accept, Accept-Language, Cookie
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Date: Sun, 08 Apr 2018 01:51:11 GMT
```

I've set compression settings to be very liberal:

[image]
[image]
[image]

FERB info for the compressed response:
[image]

FERB info for the non-compressed response:

[image]

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2017/09/05/iis-dynamic-compression-and-new-dynamic-compression-features-in-iis-10/ Scroll down to "Determine if dynamic compression is working for your content" section.

Comment: Thanks @LexLi, I've attached screenshots of FERB info

Comment: Where are the settings then? Did you put them in `web.config`?

Comment: @LexLi Which settings?

Comment: the dynamicTypes setting

Comment: @LexLi I added them using the IIS UI. They are at the app host level.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it still rellevant,
But you have to set **dynamicCompressionLevel** to a high value.
By default is 0.

[image]

Comment: I set it to 10 and still no luck.

Comment: Can you try with a smaller json? Maybe is very big JSON and bigger than buffer size.

Comment: Works with small json. Where can I change buffer size?